# EXC_ARM_BREAKPOINT when app starts - only when running on device

Tags: ios, swift

I've been developing an iOS app in Swift for a few weeks, but haven't run it on a device in a couple of weeks. I have an iPhone 4S running 7.0.6. When I start the app on a device I now get the follow error:

```
Thread 1: EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=EXC_ARM_BREAKPOINT, subcode=0xe7ffdefe)
```

Which traces back to my `AppDelegate`, line 14, which is the class signature:

`class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {`

When run on my iPad 2 running 7.0.6, I also get the following in the console:

`CoreFoundation = 847.210000`

Things I've tried:

- Clean and Build
- Deleting from device and rebooting
- Deleting derived data
- Ensuring the correct frameworks are linked (although I fear this may be one of the issues since I can build and run the project without any frameworks)
- Googling
- Running the app in simulator on multiple devices and iOS 7.1/8.0

Below is the stack trace of the error:

[image: Stack Trace from Xcode]

Comment: having the exact same issue, can't find any lead to solve this,
on my iPhone 5 7.1.2 (Jailbroken).
btw my console prints this CoreFoundation = 847.270000.

Comment: i've tested this on iPhone 5S 7.1.2 (not jailbroken) and it works.
is your iPhone 4S is jailbroken?

Comment: Both of the devices I'm testing on are jailbroken, so maybe that's the issue. I do have another app also written in Swift though, which works in both devices. Sounds like it's something to with the JB though

Comment: Starting my iPhone whilst holding the volume up button (disabling mobile substate) fixes the problem, so it's 100% a JB issue. I'll post this to the jailbreak subreddit and hopefully get results.

Comment: Works for me too, 100% JB issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be a problem with being jailbroken. I'm not entirely sure which tweak (if any) were causing it, but the issue seems to have resolved itself over time.